# Remove u' unicode from python2 script list output

Tags: python, excel, unicode, python-2.x

I have a script that scans an excel sheet and prints column A and a range of rows which outputs a list in python 2, but has the expected unicode character, which I can't seem to figure out how to get rid of after referring to several stack overflow posts.

```
(6188, u'machine1')
(6189, u'machine2')
```

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('AnsibleReadinessReviewIP.xlsx')
sheet = wb['CIsIPaddresses']
sheet['A301']
sheet['A301'].value
A = sheet['A301']
A.value
sheet.cell(row=301, column=A)
# Get the row, column, and vlaue from the cell
'Row %s, Column %s is %s' % (A.row, A.column, A.value)
'Cell %s is %s' % (A.coordinate, A.value)
sheet['A301']
for i in range('301, 6197'):
    print(i, sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value)
```

How do I remove the unicode u' from the list output? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are seeing a `u`, you are using Python 2.  In Python 2, `print` is a statement not a function, so don't call it with parentheses.  Calling with `()` make it print a tuple, and the default display for a tuple is to use `repr()` on the tuple's items.

```
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:25:58) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> i=6188
>>> value = u'machine1'
>>> print(i,value)  # prints a tuple, which uses `repr()` for items.
(6188, u'machine1')
>>> print i,value   # prints values using `str()`, which won't display `u`.
6188 machine1
```

Python 2 will only print Unicode characters that are supported by the terminal encoding, so you might get the dreaded `UnicodeEncodeError` if you have Unicode code points outside your terminal's encoding default.  Switch to Python 3 for better Unicode handling.  Python 2 is EOL.

Comment: thanks for the simple demonstration I was able to solve the issue this way. ```print i,sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value``` gave me the row numbers and hostnames that I needed

Comment: thanks for the simple demonstration I was able to solve the issue. ```print i,sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value``` and ```for i in range(301, 6197): # removed quotes to fix``` and removed the parens from ```print i,sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value``` gave me the row numbers and hostnames that I needed

Answer (score -1):

change below lines in your script:

option a:print(i, str(sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value))
option b:a.print(i, (sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value).encode('ascii',

Comment: I can't make sense of this. Use proper code formatting.

Comment: please use any 1 option  mentioned in the previous post, in your script